# printing the sequence in different order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am able to understand the logic here for the below pattern but not getting the way of implementation, please can someone help me here.

The pattern I want is like below, (in first column everything till 5, then second column after 5 leaving first and last row and so on. . )

```
1 
2 6 
3 7 9 
4 8 
5
```

Comment: you asked a question just to understand the logic behind the pattern? If you google it you will find it

Comment: @komatiraju032 i understand the logic but can you help me implement it

Comment: post the code you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(1, (n//2)+2):
    for j in range(i):
        print(i + ((n - 1) * j) - (j * (j - 1)) , end=' ')
    print()

for i in range((n//2)+2, n + 1):
    for j in range(n - i + 1):
        print(i + ((n - 1) * j) - (j * (j - 1)), end=' ')
    print()
```

**Output:**

```
n = 9
1 
2 10 
3 11 17 
4 12 18 22 
5 13 19 23 25 
6 14 20 24 
7 15 21 
8 16 
9
```

**Logic**

```
n = 9
1              |
2 10           |(10 - 2) = 8
3 11 17        |(11 - 3) = 8, (17 - 11) = 6
4 12 18 22     |(12 - 4) = 8, (18 - 12) = 6, (22 - 18) = 4
5 13 19 23 25  |(13 - 5) = 8, (19 - 13) = 6, (23 - 19) = 4, (25 - 23) = 2
6 14 20 24     |(14 - 6) = 8, (20 - 14) = 6, (24 - 20) = 4
7 15 21        |(15 - 7) = 8, (21 - 15) = 6
8 16           |(16 - 8) = 8
9              |
```

For example in line5

- first number is `5 + ((n - 1) * 0) - (0 * -1) = 5`
- next value `5 + ((n - 1) * 1) - (1 * 0) = 13`
- next value `5 + ((n - 1) * 2) - (1 * 2) = 19`
- next value `5 + ((n - 1) * 3) - (2 * 3) = 23`
- next value `5 + ((n - 1) * 4) - (3 * 4) = 25`

above 5 is `i` value and 0,1,2,3,4 are `j` values

generalised formula for calculating the value `i + ((n - 1) * j) - (j * (j - 1))`